Floating language bar app for Linux?
I can't find floating language bar app for Linux like you can do it on Windows:

I don't want the whole task bar (system panel) to always be visible but it's critical for me to take a glance on current keyboard layout sometimes. I want to auto-hide system panel but be able to see current keyboard language.
But please not KDE solution (the libs are too heavy).
